# Is it valid to provide to v-for unclosed tags for iteration in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Assume, I have such vue-code:

```
<template>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items">
        <div v-if="item.isComponent">
            <component :is="item.value"/>
        </div>
        <template v-else>
            {{item.value}}
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function(){
        return {
            items: [

              {
                value: '<p>this is first part of paragraph
              },
              {
                value: 'componentName',
                isComponent: true,
              },
              {
                value: 'this is the last part of paragraph</p>
              },

            ],
//...
</script>
```

`items` - it's a parsed (which I haven't parsed yet) string for `contenteditable` tag editor.

If this is invalid, what workaround could be?

**UPD.**

`items` is a json which I will get from database which should be saved to database as user input to `contenteditable` div editor.

Answer (score 0):

Html will get sanitize the Html part. So it is not a good idea. to do such things.
Html should be kept in template of vue.
But let say you wanted to show some data in

tag. Instead of doing use computed prop and hide and show p tag. It also prevents the incomplete tag issue.

I am attaching jsfiddle solution[

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    items: [

              {
                value: '<p>this is first part of paragraph'
              },
              {
                value: 'componentName',
                isComponent: true,
              },
              {
                value: 'this is the last part of paragraph</p>'
              },

            ],
  },
  computed:{
  dataVal(){
  let val = "";
  for(let i=0;i<this.items.length;i++){
  val += this.items[i].value + " "
  }
  return val;
  }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" v-html="dataVal">
</div>
```

][1](https://jsfiddle.net/shashankgpt270/n6z2m17k/1/)

Comment: I have made update to my question about storing html to `items`.

Comment: okay.Edited my answer as well.Now try Try this one-> (above one) https://jsfiddle.net/shashankgpt270/n6z2m17k/6/

Comment: You are using `v-html="dataVal"` which means I will lose component functionality which is within the `items`.

Comment: It is important to me to use `<component :is="item.value"/>`.

Comment: but in that case, you are passing a broken Html to your component which not correct

Comment: With `v-html` I will lose reactivity of the components inside `items`.

Comment: you can use watcher or computed prop to check reactivity